# TicTacToe how to count wins, counter - help needed

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck. What I need is counter to wins values.
I did tictactoe by this tutorial : http://hubpages.com/technology/tictactoe. I've complete it and now I'd like to add something by myself, and it's just a counter of how many times someone won.

```
//if mWinner = CIRCLE
    //increase @+id/cross_wins by 1
//if mWinner = CROSS
    //increase @+id/circles_wins by 1
//else increase @+id/draws by 1
```

that is all what I want, could you show me how to code it proper?

[image: I want the "0" on this to change, if crosses,circles wins the game or it's a draw, just to tick +1]

```
package com.example.jkaminski.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    makeScreen();
    initialize();
}

private void makeScreen() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

private ImageView[] mBlocks = new ImageView[9];
private TextView mDisplay;
private LinearLayout mExit, mReplay;

private enum TURN {CIRCLE, CROSS}

private TURN mTurn;
private int mExitCounter = 0;
private int mStatusCounter = 0;

private void initialize() {
    mExit = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    mExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mExitCounter == 1) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                mExitCounter++;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Naciśnij ponownie aby wyjść", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_board);
    mReplay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.replay);
    mReplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent starter = getIntent();
            finish();
            starter.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(starter);
        }
    });
    for (int position = 0; position < 9; position++) {
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("block_" + (position + 1), "id", getPackageName());
        mBlocks[position] = (ImageView) findViewById(resId);
        final int finalPosition = position;
        mBlocks[position].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switchTurn(finalPosition);
            }
        });

    }
}

private void switchTurn(int position) {
    if (mTurn == TURN.CIRCLE) {
        mBlocks[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
        mBlocks[position].setId(GameLogic.CIRCLE);
        mTurn = TURN.CROSS;
        mDisplay.setText("teraz KRZYŻYK");
    } else {
        mBlocks[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
        mBlocks[position].setId(GameLogic.CROSS);
        mTurn = TURN.CIRCLE;
        mDisplay.setText("teraz KÓŁKO");
    }
    mBlocks[position].setEnabled(false);
    mStatusCounter++;
    if (GameLogic.isCompleted(position + 1, mBlocks)) {
        mDisplay.setText(GameLogic.sWinner + " zostaje zwycięzcą!");
        displayStick(GameLogic.sSet);
        disableAll();
    } else if (mStatusCounter == 9) {
        mDisplay.setText("REMIS. Spróbuj ponownie ;)");
    }
}

private void displayStick(int stick) {
    View view;
    switch (stick) {
        case 1:
            view = findViewById(R.id.top_horizontal);
            break;
        case 2:
            view = findViewById(R.id.center_horizontal);
            break;
        case 3:
            view = findViewById(R.id.bottom_horizontal);
            break;
        case 4:
            view = findViewById(R.id.left_vertical);
            break;
        case 5:
            view = findViewById(R.id.center_vertical);
            break;
        case 6:
            view = findViewById(R.id.right_vertical);
            break;
        case 7:
            view = findViewById(R.id.left_right_diagonal);
            break;
        case 8:
            view = findViewById(R.id.right_left_diagonal);
            break;
        default://which will never happen
            view = findViewById(R.id.top_horizontal);
    }
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void disableAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        mBlocks[i].setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}

private void showResults() {
    if (GameLogic.mWinner == GameLogic.CIRCLE) {

    } else if (GameLogic.mWinner == GameLogic.CROSS) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

}

```
package com.example.jkaminski.myapplication;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GameLogic {

private static ImageView[] sBlocks;
public static String sWinner;
public static int sSet;

public static final int CIRCLE = 0;
public static final int CROSS = 1;

public static int mWinner;


private static boolean areSameInSet(int first, int second, int third, int set) {
    boolean value = sBlocks[first - 1].getId() == sBlocks[second - 1].getId() && sBlocks[second - 1].getId() == sBlocks[third - 1].getId();
    if (value) {
        if (sBlocks[first - 1].getId() == CIRCLE) {
            mWinner = CIRCLE;
            sWinner = "KÓŁKO";
        } else {
            mWinner = CROSS;
            sWinner = "KRZYŻYK";
        }
        sSet = set;
    }
    return value;
}


public static boolean isCompleted(int position, ImageView[] blocks) {
    GameLogic.sBlocks = blocks;
    boolean isComplete = false;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(1, 2, 3, 1) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 4, 7, 4) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 5, 9, 7);
            break;
        case 2:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(1, 2, 3, 1) ||
                    areSameInSet(2, 5, 8, 5);
            break;
        case 3:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(1, 2, 3, 1) ||
                    areSameInSet(3, 6, 9, 6) ||
                    areSameInSet(3, 5, 7, 8);
            break;
        case 4:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(4, 5, 6, 2) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 4, 7, 4);
            break;
        case 5:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(4, 5, 6, 2) ||
                    areSameInSet(2, 5, 8, 5) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 5, 9, 7) ||
                    areSameInSet(3, 5, 7, 8);
            break;
        case 6:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(4, 5, 6, 2) ||
                    areSameInSet(3, 6, 9, 6);
            break;
        case 7:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(7, 8, 9, 3) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 4, 7, 4) ||
                    areSameInSet(3, 5, 7, 8);
            break;
        case 8:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(7, 8, 9, 3) ||
                    areSameInSet(2, 5, 8, 5);
            break;
        case 9:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(7, 8, 9, 3) ||
                    areSameInSet(3, 6, 9, 6) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 5, 9, 7);
            break;
    }
    return isComplete;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you should try to add 1 to some variable when GameLogic.isComplete()

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use static class variables to record such counters.
Just in the method the game concludes, +1 the relevant variable.

Comment: Sadly, but after tapping to new game, whole activity restars - not only the grid, so I think I can't use that. It would delete my counts

Answer (score 1):

When the game completes you need to increment some counter. You have a lot of options. You might use a `static` variable as others have suggested:

```
private static int numWins = 0;

...

if (GameLogic.isCompleted(position + 1, mBlocks)) { 
    numWins++;
    ....
```

but my suggestion is to persist the value using `SharedPreferences`. You will need code for saving and loading the counter.

```
public static int loadNumWins( Context context )
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return prefs.getInt("numWins", 0);
}

public static void saveNumWins( Context context, int value )
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    prefs.putInt("numWins", value);
    prefs.commit();
}
```

and then code to use the counter...

```
if (GameLogic.isCompleted(position + 1, mBlocks)) 
{ 
    int numWins = loadNumWins(this);   // load value from prefs
    numWins++;                         // increment it
    saveNumWins(this, numWins);        // save it back to prefs
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for that comment, could you specify me these things; there are 3 values so do I need to create 3 code examples like that? Where do I need to paste it, I mean, how should I implement it to make it work. After that - displaying it to xml by setContentView?

Comment: yes, you will need code (like above) to store/retrieve the values. That code is pretty much identical except for the key used to identify the value - I used "numWins", but I guess you also want "numWinsX", "numWinsO", etc.   Put the static functions on your Activity class, and call them from the `if` statement that determines if a win occurred - they take a `Context` as a parameter - in this case the Context is your main Activity (so you will pass `this` to your functions). To display you will need a TextView in your xml - use `findViewById` to get it and then use `setText`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest way you can do this is by adding some static counter variables to the class and then incrementing them and updating the screen when you determine the winner.